# Binary search for List<object>

Tags: c#, list, methods, binary-search

Hello I need some help in my library. I'm trying to implement a binary search from my `List<>` but its not working so well.

This is my Library class.

```
    private class Library
{
    List<object> library = new List<object>();

    public void AddBook(string bookName, string bookAuthor, int bookIDNum)
    {
        //Add books to the library.
        string bookEntry = bookName + " " + bookAuthor + " " + bookIDNum;
        library.Add(bookEntry);
        library.TrimExcess();
    }

        public void SearchLibrary(string bookName)
    {
        //Searches the library by title
        library.Sort();
        int low = 0;
        int high = library.Count;
        int mid = 0;
        int steps = 0;
        while(!bookName)
        {
            steps++;
            mid = (low + high)/2;
            if(bookName == library[mid])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(bookName < library[mid])
            {
                high = mid;
            }
            else
            {
                low = mid;
            }
            if(low > high-1 || high < low+1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If there's a better way I can make a search method I would appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here... : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please show sample that makes sense/compiles. Clearly `public void SearchLibrary(){... return true;...}` is not valid code.

Comment: How do you plan to do a binary search on unsorted data? Why does your `List` contain `object`? Why is your `void` method trying to  return boolean values? Why wouldn't a search method return the index of the matching value, or the matching value itself?

Comment: So... why do you have a `List<object>` when all you do is put `string`s in?

Comment: By the way, think about using Dictionary<string,string> instead of List<object>. Or maybe SortedList<string,string> if sorting is important.

Comment: @jimmyfever I am sure you meant `HashSet<string>` when you said `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: @Aron I think  jimmyfever meant `Dictionary<string, BookEntry>` indexed by `bookName` for O(1) search...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without commenting on the details of your algorithm, there are some issues with your code. You could've found all these issues by looking at the compiler's error messages.

- You return `true` and `false`, yet your method specifies it returns `void`. Change that to `bool` instead.

  ```
  public bool SearchLibrary(string bookName)
  ```
- You do `!bookName`, where I presume you want to check whether it is `null` or not. You must do that explicitly in C#.

  ```
  while (bookName != null)
  ```
- You compare two strings, but the `<` operator is not overloaded for strings. Use `CompareTo` instead:

  ```
  else if (bookName.CompareTo(library[mid]) < 0)
  ```
- Not all code paths return a value. You'll have to return a value no matter what execution path it takes. For example, end your method with this:

  ```
  return false;
  ```

Then there is an issue with your algorithm: it will run forever when there is no match. As I suspect this may be homework, I'll leave it an an exercise for the OP to solve this issue.

---

And if this isn't a homework exercise, you could've saved yourself some trouble:

The `List<T>` class has a method [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) that uses the default comparer to compare the objects in the list.

```
library.Sort();
bool found = (library.BinarySearch(bookName) >= 0);
```

Comment: +1: For detailed writeup. Note for current content of the list search will *never* find the match as `bookName` is never stored alone in the list (other info appended to it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In the code that I see, there is no call to `SearchLibrary`, so I don't know whether the correct string is passed to it. Note that `bookName` as used in `SearchLibrary` and `bookName` as used in `AddBook` are distinct variables that have no visible relationship.

Comment: Technically right - if `bookName` is not a name of a book but rather complete value of item that it would work fine... Also I hope variable name reflects it meaning (at least some effort went into finding good name).

Comment: By the way thank you for the comments. I'm really new to this and all of comments are helpful!